# Can we make array of sets in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Like the following way:

```
set<int> s[3];
```

I have tried it but it gives error in the line where I had tried to access its elements by writing `s[i][j]` where the error says

> no match for 'operator[ ]'

Comment: Why not `std::vector<std::set<int>>`?

Comment: `std::set` doesn't have an `operator[]`...

Comment: there isn't `operator[]` for `std::set`

Comment: Of course you can, but as has been said, `set` doesn't have `operator[]`:  https://ideone.com/WZj40n

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not the array of `std::set`-s but rather the way you try to access elements inside your set.

`std::set` doesn't support `operator []`, that is why you are getting the error:

> no match for 'operator[ ]'

Instead, access object using `find()` in the following way:

```
auto iter = s[i].find(<value>);
if (iter != s[i].end()) {
    [..] // Do something with iter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Elements of a set are not accessed by index. s[i] is the (i-1)'th set but s[i][j] doesn't mean anything. You can check whether an element is present in the set    using the find function. For eg s[i].find(3)!=s[i].end() . You can loop through the elements in sorted order using for(int x : s[i]){} (C++11 and above) or using iterators.